# Incoherence found between c_str(), length() and size()

Tags: c++, string, null, unordered-map, c-strings

I am building a map from a text file using the std::unordered_map data structure, using the pair < uint64_t id, BaseDevice device >.
BaseDevice is a structure, containing a 64-bit id and a string:

```
struct BaseDevice
{
public:
    uint64_t id;
    string ipAddress;
}
```

I read a file (assuming that it is correctly written) and build the map as follows:

```
char buffer[1024];
ifstream fin(myfile.c_str());

while(fin.eof() == false)
{
  fin.getline(buffer, 1023);
  StringTokenizer st(buffer, " ");

  //Parse ID and address
  unsigned int id = atoi(st.nextToken().c_str()); //get ID
  string ipAddress = st.nextToken();  //get IP address

  //Create the local structure and add to the map
  BaseDevice dev;
  dev.id = id;
  dev.ipAddress = ipAddress;
  myMap[id] = dev;

  break;
}
```

The strange thing is that when I traverse my map, the ipAddress string seems to be (null), while both length() and size() are not.

```
unordered_map< string, BaseDevice >::const_iterator itr1;
for(itr1 = myMap.begin(); itr1 != myMap.end(); itr1++)
{
  const BaseDevice& device = itr1->second;
  fprintf(stdout, "id %lu ipAddress %s \n", myMap->first, device.ipAddress);
  printf("Length is %d \n", device.ipAddress.length());
  printf("Size is %d \n", device.ipAddress.size());

  /*
  OUTPUT:

  id 2 ipAddress (null)
  Length is 8  
  Size is 8
  */
}
```

I would like to ask you: how is this possible? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `fprintf()` gives undefined behaviour if the format specifier is inconsistent with the type of the corresponding argument.  `%s` assumes a C-style string (represented as an array of `char`, terminated with a zero value).  A `std::string` is not a C style string.   Why are you using C++ iostreams in some code, and `fprintf()` in other code?   That is a prime recipe for confusion.

Comment: `eof()` is [not a good condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) for your loop. You should instead be making sure that `getline` succeeds instead of blindly assuming it does. Also note that all major compilers currently warn on mismatched `printf` types. Turn up your compiler warnings.

Comment: @Peter, you are right, I am mixing few things. I am used to C syntax, and quite new to the C++ environment.

Comment: @chris I think that I will change the loop condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing `device.ipAddress` as if it was a C-string (with `%s` format specifier), which is incorrect, so `fprintf` may go nuts while trying to print it. You should do:

```
fprintf(stdout, "...%s...", device.ipAddress.c_str());
```

You can also do the same with `std::cout`:

```
std::cout << device.ipAddress << '\n';
```